# how to extract JSON array from the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am inserted json array without any key value into database Now i want extract json array to single values

Database table stored like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j09C8.png

i want to display like this

```
13
53
76
3
71
17
9
```

i tried like this

```
 <?php
     $members_id=$this->db->get_where('ag_matched_members', array('staff_id' =>$msgdata->staff_id))->row()->members_id;
                      $members_ids = json_decode($members_id, true);
                   ?>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <i class="fa fa-envelope text-aqua"></i> <?php echo $members_ids[0];  ?>
                        </a>
                      </li>
```

Comment: use `json_decode()` and print the array

Comment: What do you mean by display? You mean print to the console? HTML?

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Just the formatting as JSON?

Comment: check above link

Comment: Add loop to print $members_ids array's items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Code :

```
<?php
    $res = $this->db->query("SELECT members_id FROM `ag_matched_members` WHERE staff_id =  ? " , $msgdata->staff_id )->result_array();
    $members_ids = explode(',', json_decode($res[0]['members_id'])[0]);
    foreach($members_ids as $id){
        echo('<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope text-aqua"></i> '.$id.'</a></li>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: how to display one by one ?

Comment: you can use foreach($members_ids as $id){ echo($id); }

Comment: I Will Update The Answer, Check It!